# Issue with Objects.nonNull() behavior

Tags: java

Using Java 11. Noticing a strange behavior with very simple functionality. In the following code, if the expiration date is not null, only then it should try to extract the `sql.Timestamp` from the given `Instant` field.

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(expirationDateParameterIndex,
                            Objects.nonNull(memberReward.getExpirationDate())
                            ? Timestamp.from(memberReward.getExpirationDate())
                            : null);
```

Problem is that even though the expiration date is set to `null`, `Timestamp.from(..)` is called and throwing `NullPointerException`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.sql/java.sql.Timestamp.from(Timestamp.java:545)
```

The issue is not reproducible outside the project.

Here are the debugging screenshots:
[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Can you try and extract the value returned by `memberReward.getExpirationDate()` into a local variable?

Comment: Why would you use `Objects.nonNull` in this case instead of `!=null`?

Comment: @Turing85 `Objects::nonNull` can be useful as a predicate (but not in this case).

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Timestamp`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead since JDBC 4.2 in the non-null case try `memberReward.getExpirationDate().atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC)` and pass the resulting `OffsetDateTime` using `preparedStatement.setObject()`. `OffsetDateTime` is a class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for the recommendation and for sharing the links. I'm going to read on this and make the necessary code changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, your debug screenshot is clear: `null` was passed to `Timestamp.from()`, which means `memberReward.getExpirationDate()` **is null**.

That's weird, because right before that, you check for that condition! Thus, we get to these explanations, all quite exotic:

- `getExpirationDate()` is non-stable: It returns different values every time. Imagine it was implemented as follows: `return random.coinFlip() == HEADS ? null : someDateObj;` - then this can happen. One way to fix this is to call it once, save to a local variable, and carry on with that.
- expirationDate is not immutable, and some other thread is setting the value in between your check and your read. This is unlikely, but technically possible, and suggests you need a serious rewrite of it all, having such casual shared mutable state between threads means this is just one of a ton of race conditions.
- The code you're seeing is not the code that is running.
- You're getting to Timestamp.from from different code than what you pasted.
- That is not the Objects of `java.util`, and the nonNull method on it, is broken.

These all sound exotic, but it must be one of these things.

Comment: The third one happens more often than one would think.

Comment: Sorry to waste everyone's time here. The application was running on Docker. After your message, I updated all images and that resolved the issue. Your third point was very helpful. Thank you.